# Why the ItemsSource in WPF DataGrid IGNORES GetEnumerator() in my bound collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I try to implement filtering in my own observable collection.
My approach is following:
I assume the control using `ItemsSource` should call `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` on my collection to get the items it should render. So I define my own `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` to apply filtering.

Here's relevant code:

```cs
public Func<T, bool>? Filter { get; set; }

public void Refresh() {
    OnCollectionChanged(
        new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
            NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset
        )
    );
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    => Filter is null
        ? (IEnumerator)BaseIEnumerableGetEnumerator.Invoke(this, null)!
        : this.Where(Filter).GetEnumerator();

public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    => Filter is null
        ? base.GetEnumerator()
        : this.Where(Filter).GetEnumerator();

private static readonly MethodInfo BaseIEnumerableGetEnumerator
    = BaseType.GetMethod(
        "System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
    )!;
```

BTW, my base class is `List<T>`. It also implements `IList`, `ICollection`, `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Now - I set the filter.
Nothing happens.
So I call `Refresh()`.

And to my surprise also nothing happens. Why? When `Reset` is sent to the ItemsCollection - the control should reload, and while reloading it should call `GetEnumerator()`.

I set the breakpoint on my `GetEnumerator()` method, but it is not called on `Refresh`. WHY?

To clarify - I try to replicate exact `ListCollectionView` feature. It contains `Refresh()` method that applies the filtering.

Another weird thing I see is that my new `GetEnumerator()` is called by my own control, but it is not called AT ALL by `DataGrid`.

UPDATE:

As I've recently researched - built-in WPF controls might use some undocumented magic to bind items. They can trigger events on view model objects - that is possible (AFAIK) with `Reflection`.

IDK, using `Reflection` in the view you could dig into "underlying System Type" and use it's indexer if it's available to get items. In that case - it would just not use `GetEnumerator`.

I also checked the source code of `ListCollectionView`:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Data/ListCollectionView.cs

It just uses a kind of shadow collection to achieve filtering. Well, that one way to achieve the effect for sure. But the easiest, if not the fastest way to filter any collection is to inject the filter into it's enumeration. No objects are created, no allocations, that should be fast. And easy. It works in my own control, that uses `foreach` on `ItemsSource`. It's obvious, `foreach` calls enumerator. There's no way around it. However, Microsoft's control obviously either don't use `foreach` or... they operate on something different than just the original items collection.

Comment: A lot of data-binding special-cases `IList` - I wonder if that is a factor here (idle speculation)

Comment: Good shot! I tested it - it calls `IList` indexer to get items! I don't know yet why, but I'm investigating it... BTW, weirdly it calls the indexer MULTIPLE times for a single item. It seems to be not a very efficient approach.

Comment: tip: if you store the enumerator you get from the .Where(...), and you keep track of the last index requested - you can do something like "is it the same index again? then return iter.Current; is the index ahead? then try using iter.MoveNext() until we're at the right place (which will usually mean: the next one), and then use iter.Current; is the indexer behind? get a new enumerator completely (you should never call iter.Reset(); that API is dead and unusable)

Comment: Another good one, I'll use it. BTW, I checked, it uses indexer so I created a shadow list on filtering applied and it just works. My collection behaves the same as `ListCollectionView` (using similar technique). If no filtering is used, the original (base) list is used, no performance hit, there is a cost of the shadow list on filtering applied. But this is true also for `ListCollectionView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemsControl (including DataGrid, Listbox, etc.) works with the collection not directly, but through ICollectionView.
When a collection does not provide its own ICollectionView implementation (which is almost always the case), the ItemsControl itself creates the most suitable wrapper for it.
Typically, this is a CollectionView and types derived from it.
An example of a class that provides its own wrapper is CompositeCollection.
It provides a wrapper for the CompositeCollectionView.

The CollectionViewSource is also a means to create an ICollectionView for your collection.
Including using the GetDefaultView () method, you can return the default view of your collection.
This is what the ItemsControl uses when you pass your collection to it.
For almost all collections, a ListCollectionView will be a wrapper.
With the resulting wrapper, you can set properties to filter, group, sort, and render the collection view.

If you want to create your own presentation rules for your collection, then you need to implement the [ICollectionViewFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icollectionviewfactory?view=netframework-4.8) interface.
It has only one CreateView() method that returns the View wrapper for your collection.
You will have to create your own ICollectionView implementation (it's easier to do this based on the CollectionView or ListCollectionView classes).
And then return its instance in the CreateView() method.

Comment: Thanks, that completes the puzzle. I need to optimize my view that allows searching in a large collection of pretty big rows. It's pretty slow on typing the first 2 letters, so it will surely go faster if it won't copy the items 2 times, that is probably happening in my app.

Comment: I think you can hardly think of anything better than using a CollectionViewSource.
Have you tried just setting a filter for your collection through it?
If the collection can change, then it should be an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

OK, `DataGrid` just doesn't use `GetEnumerator` to display items.
It uses `IList.this[index]` and `ICollection.Count` for that.

So to implement filtering on my collection I had to create a `ShadowList` that contains filtered items.

Then I provided overrides for `IList.this[index]` and `ICollection.Count` to return items from the `ShadowList`.

Then I updated all adding to my collection to also update the `ShadowList` if the added item matches the `Filter`.

It works, however there's a catch: the filtered data is accessible only via `IList` indexer. So if the consuming control uses it - it will get filtered data, if not - it will get the original data.

I think it's preferable here. My view model needs original collection most of the time, and if it's not the case - I can always apply filter adding `.Where(collection.Filter)` to the enumerator.

`GetEnumerator` is called A LOT in a complex view model so it's best if it is the original `List<T>` enumerator.

The completed collection (`ObservableList<T>`) is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/HTD/Woof.Windows/blob/master/Woof.Windows.Mvvm/ObservableList.cs

Answer (score 0):

> It just uses a kind of shadow collection to achieve filtering.

For the WPF DataGrid, I believe it uses a backing `CollectionViewSource`, so filtering is a little bit different (as you say, it has a shadow collection).

[MSDN has some info on filtering using the WPF DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#filtering-items-in-a-datagrid) that I think might be helpful in your case.

Comment: The `ItemsSource` is defined just as `IEnumerable` so it can display practically any collection, however, it CAN use `CollectionViewSource` that provides filtering. My goal was to replicate some of its behavior in my own class to implement extra features, like capacity set ahead of time, IDisposable item and such. I wondered WHICH exact features of `CollectionViewSource` were used and I figured it out.